# XtraReport doesnt Display the Sub Report

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, report, xtrareport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use SubReport in XtraReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966918/how-to-use-subreport-in-xtrareport)

I'm having a problem with my XtraReport 
it doesnt display the Sub Report but it Displays the main Report
here's my Code

```
Dim report As New XSalesReport()
    Dim ds As New DSProducts
    Dim sSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sSQL.AppendLine("SELECT  ")
    sSQL.AppendLine("*")
    sSQL.AppendLine("FROM PaymentTransactions ")

    Dim zSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    zSQL.AppendLine("SELECT  ")
    zSQL.AppendLine("*")
    zSQL.AppendLine("FROM DailyTransactions ")

    CreateWaitDialog()
    SetWaitDialogCaption("Loading Report Data")
    Using SQLconnect As New SQLiteConnection(g_constring)
        SQLconnect.Open()
        Dim SQLAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sSQL.ToString, SQLconnect)
        SQLAdapter.Fill(ds.Payment)
        Dim SQLAdapter1 As New SQLiteDataAdapter(zSQL.ToString, SQLconnect)
        SQLAdapter1.Fill(ds.DailyTransaction)
    End Using
    report.DataSource = ds
    report.ShowPreview()
    CloseWaitDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.. I just put a relation in both `datatable`..